# Getting the row-index from an OutlierTest table

Tags: r, row-number, outliers

I have run an OutlierTest on a regression model and assigned it to a variable. The `class` of the table is also `outlierTest`. I want to extract the row index from this table.

I am not able to convert the table into a `data.frame` or a `matrix`.

```
> library(car)

> b <- outlierTest(fit_train2)

> b
     rstudent unadjusted p-value Bonferonni p
411  4.976415         1.0296e-06   0.00036243
372  4.160773         4.0193e-05   0.01414800
401 -3.987709         8.1658e-05   0.02874400
373  3.881285         1.2474e-04   0.04391000
```

I basically need something to extract `411, 372, 401` and `373` into another vector.

Alternatively, is there any function that provides me with the row-numbers of the influential observations in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any of the elements of the object and take the names of that. 
For example,

```
names(b$bonf.p)
```

or

```
names(n[[1]])
```

Comment: That's a surprisingly simple solution. Thank you. :)